# Is it possible to conduct ANOVA with a frequency variable?

Tags: r, anova

[image]I conducted a content analysis on social media posts regarding CEO communication about sociopolitical topics. I have two levels of analysis entities: 1) the social media account of a CEO, 2) the social media posts per account.

One question I wanted to examine (on the level of 1) social media accounts) is whether the affiliation of an account to a specific industry does correlate with the number of sociopolitical posts - in other words, do the CEO social media accounts of specific industries have more sociopolitical posts than others?

I conducted a one-way ANOVA with "industry of account" as my independent variable, which is a nominal variable (codes "1" to "7§), and the "number of sociopolitical posts" as my explained variable, which is continuous (no codes, but frequency numbers, ranges from 1 to 76).

That's the code I used:

```
data$industry <- as.factor(data$industry)
anova <- aov(post_sp ~ industry, data = data)
etaSquared(anova, anova = TRUE)
pairwise.t.test(data$post_sp, data$industry)
```

Everything worked well except for the pairwise Posthoc test, I didn't receive any data. That's when I asked myself if it's even possible to conduct an ANOVA with the variable "number of sociopolitical posts", or if I have to recode it somehow.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you 'didn't receive any data'? maybe provide a screenshot of your console after running the code. Also, It seems your dependent variable is count data, whereas ANOVA needs continuous, preferably normally distributed responses according to the assumptions. In such cases, a generalized linear model (Poisson / Negative Binomial regression) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Your code works with the following toy example: `data=data.frame(industry=c(rep("A",10), rep("B", 10), rep("C", 8)), post_sp=c(1:7, 1:3, 3:7, 3:7, 1:4, 1:4))`  and assuming you use `library(lsr)` if that's what you are using for `etaSquared()`.

Comment: @DevD I just uploaded a picture of the console. Aren't linear models for continuous variables only? So both, the explanatory and explained variable have to bee continuous?

Comment: You'd be better off including a small reproducible example, including toy data, that shows the problem.  As I mentioned, the code you posted works fine with a simple example.

Comment: Linear models are *not* for continuous data only. See Jacob Cohen (1968), "Multiple regression as a general data-analytic system" (PDF), Psychological Bulletin, 70 (6): 426–443, https://web.archive.org/web/20110611044717/http://www.unt.edu/rss/class/mike/6810/articles/Cohen1968glm.pdf

Comment: Thank you @SalMangiafico! I will try again with the toy data

Comment: Okay thank you @MikeHunter, will look into linear models as well

Comment: @KateVasi There are different linear models for different data types. you can search Google to see the appropriate model for discrete response and categorical predictor.